# R data frame rearraangement

Tags: r

I have an R data frame (actually an excel sheet which I have read into R) in the format below:

```
ID      Text
1      This is a red
       car. Its electric
       and has 4 wheels.
2      This is a van with
       six wheels.
```

I want to reshape it into the following format

```
ID     Text
1      This is a red car. Its electric and has 4 wheels.
2      This is a van with six wheels
```

Essentially between the two ID numbers my text has been broken into multiple lines. I want to combine it to look like the output above.
Using group_by a numeric ID did not work as it gets rid of lines w/o the ID#.
Any thoughts on how I can achieve this type of output?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data with `dput()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`.  Convert the blank (`""`) in 'ID' to `NA` (`na_if`), using `fill` from `tidyr`, change the `NA` elements to previous non-Na value, grouped by 'ID', then `paste` the 'Text' by `collapse`ing the elements together to a single string

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
      mutate(ID = na_if(ID, "")) %>%
      fill(ID) %>%
       group_by(ID) %>%
      summarise(Text = str_c(Text, collapse=' '))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   ID    Text                                             
#  <chr> <chr>                                            
#1 1     This is a red car. Its electric and has 4 wheels.
#2 2     This is a van with six wheels.
```

---

Or create a logical index converted to numeric to fill the 'ID' and use that as grouping variable to `summarise` the 'Text' column

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID = ID[ID != ""][cumsum(ID != "")]) %>%
    summarise(Text = str_c(Text, collapse=" "))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  ID    Text                                             
#  <chr> <chr>                                            
#1 1     This is a red car. Its electric and has 4 wheels.
#2 2     This is a van with six wheels.
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("1", "", "", "2", ""), Text = c("This is a red", 
"car. Its electric", "and has 4 wheels.", "This is a van with", 
"six wheels.")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```